# Casting query in VB.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am very new to visual studio basics. And I am working on a small project. I have a GirdView to display a list of courses Students can view it's price also. I'm trying to use a DropDownList to determine the currency output under the column "Price" of Course Table.

I have tried,
Convert.ToDouble(query) and ToDecimal(query)

I am still getting "Input string was not in correct format" error

My "Price" column in Course Table is of type decimal(18,2)

Can someone explain to me in simple terms what I am doing wrong and help please.

```
  Protected Sub DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DropDownList2.SelectedIndexChanged
         Dim cc As CurrencyConverter = New CurrencyConverter

         sqlCon.Open()
         Dim query As String
         query = "SELECT Price from dbo.Course"

         If DropDownList2.SelectedValue.Equals("USD") Then
             query = cc.USDtoSGD(query)
         Else
             query = cc.SGDtoUSD(query)
         End If
         sqlCon.Close()
     End Sub
```

My code in the Webservice,

```
 <WebMethod()>
 Public Function SGDtoUSD(SGD As Double) As Double
     Return Math.Round((SGD * 0.72), 2)
 End Function

 <WebMethod()>
 Public Function USDtoSGD(USD As Double) As Double
     Return Math.Round((USD * 1.39), 2)
 End Function
```

Comment: in the variable Quary is a string "SELECT Price from dbo.Course". and you are passing the variable USDtoSGD function which is expecting double.

Comment: Does the method USDtoSGD take a SQL statement and convert it into currency? I'm suspecting not. You have to execute the query and feed its result to your Currency Converter.

Comment: You need to do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to convert your query, which is the string, "SELECT Price from dbo.Course", to a double.  This is obviously not possible.

What you want to do is EXECUTE your query, and store the result in a variable, and pass that resulting variable to your function that expects a double.

Presumably, its the Price that you want to convert to a certain currency, and not the string "SELECT Price from dbo.Course".

Queries do not automatically become their results.  They have to be explicitly executed, and their results have to be explicitly stored.